How to overlay only part of a video using ffmpeg or a similar tool (not the full frame)
I have two videos (let's say 1.mp4 and 2.mp4). I would like to overlay only the top-right quarter of 2.mp4 onto 1.mp4.
The output would be a single video with the content from 1.mp4 in the top left, bottom left and bottom right, and the content from 2.mp4 in the top right.
(To be clear, I don't mean shrinking anything. The output would show only three quarters of the frame from 1.mp4 and only one quarter of the frame from 2.mp4)
Is it possible to do this with ffmpeg or something similar?

ffmpeg 7 → ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -lavfi " [1][0]scale=rw/2:rh/2[a]; [0][a]overlay=W/2:0 " -c:a copy out.mp4, ffmpeg <7 → [1][0]scale2ref=main_w/2:main_h/2[a][b]; [b][a]overlay=main_w/2:0

OP wants to overlap a cropped portion, not a rescaled video.

Ah, my bad. this? → ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -lavfi " [1]crop=iw/2:ih/2:iw/2:0[a]; [0][a]overlay=W/2:0 " -c:a copy /tmp/out.mp4

Any Video Converter is recommended to overlay another video on a video file. You can use it to customize overlays to suit any video by changing their position, size, duration, or create your own layout such as side by side.

Run the Any Video Converter program, and click the "Video Overlay" option on the main interface.


Choose the video file you want to overlay with other video.


Click the "Add" button to choose another video you want to overlap the original one. You can add multiple videos and adjust the transparency of the video.


Click the "Start" button to start the video overlay.


When it finishes, the output file will be listed in the "History" panel automatically. You can open the folder to view the video which has been modified.



